# SQL Server grouping by an irregular pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column indicating how a group of rows belong together. It looks like this:

```
groups
------
NULL
1
1
NULL
1
1
1
1
NULL
1
NULL
NULL
NULL
1
1
1
1
1
1
...
```

Here, `Null` is always the first row of a group. Following 1s belong to the nearest `NULL` above.

If there's only one `NULL`, there's only one row in a group. Each group can vary from 1 to 20 rows, more or less.

I want to add a column that allocates the same number/code that is unique to each group, so I can partition by that column. How can it be done? I could think of several ways to do this in R. However, there are nearly 5 million rows, and I need to do this in SQL Server considering the processing time. :(

Below is something I wish to achieve

```
groups      group_id
---------------------
NULL        1
1           1
1           1  
NULL        2
1           2
1           2
1           2
1           2
NULL        3 
1           3
NULL        4
NULL        5
NULL        6
1           6
1           6
1           6
1           6
1           6
1           6
...
```

Comment: Your results rely on an ordering for the data.  However, no column specifies the ordering and SQL tables are *unordered*.  Is there such a column?

Comment: Oh yes! there is a column for row numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically, multi-sets).  So, you need a column that specifies the ordering.  With such a column all you want is a cumulative conditional sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when groups is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering column>) as group_id
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb456f34ddc6d777cc1ce7a16d582f79) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: `rows unbounded preceding`